# Which versions of Android support Material 3 (MD3)

Tags: android, android-studio, material-ui, material-design

I started doing a research about Material 3 support and can't find a version list of which Android versions support Material 3 design library (MD3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material library supports Android 4.0 and up (API level 14)

> Material Components for Android is a static library that you can add
> to your Android application in order to use APIs that provide
> implementations of the Material Design specification. Compatible on
> devices running API 14 or later.

According to latest 1.6.1 version: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1